# How to change Run Configurations of a JUnit Test in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit, environment-variables

I need to set some key/value pair in Environment section of Run Configurations file for my JUnit test class. However, if I add this value manually from eclipse, I can't push it to git repository because other people might work on another IDEs. How can I set the environment variable for this test run configuration  file from java source code in the test suite? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be part of the unit test setup, not part of the IDE configuration.

Comment: @RealSkeptic how can I do that setup?:)

Comment: This guide includes an example of how to set system properties from a file at runtime: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html But I would generally avoid that and rather use configuration from files directly, without setting them as global properties.